# Hadoop 2.x on amazon ec2 t2.micro

Tags: hadoop, amazon-ec2, hadoop-yarn, hadoop2

I'm trying to install and configure Hadoop 2.6 on Amazon EC2 t2.micro instance (The Free one, with only 1GB RAM) in Pseudo-Distributed Mode.
I could configure and start all the daemons (ie. Namenode,Datanode,ResourceManager,NodeManager). But When I tried to run a mapreduce wordcount example, it is failing.
I dont know if its failing due to low memory ( Since t2.micro has only 1GB of memory and some of it is taken up by Host OS, Ubuntu in my case). Or can it be some other reason?
I'm using default memory settings. If I can tweak down everything to minimum memory settings will it solve the problem? What is the minimum memory in mb that can be assigned to containers.
Thanks a lot Guys. I'll appreciate if you can provide me with some information.

Comment: In my opinion it's waste of time to try running Hadoop stack on 1GB RAM server. It is most probably failing because of memory as you mentioned. You can check logs and you will see.

Comment: I have successfully configured hadoop-1.2.1 on t2.micro instance in standalone as well as fully distributed mode (using 5 t2.micros). I ran mapreduce jobs on it and it worked perfectly fine. I guess Hadoop-2.x will also run on t2.micro if I can properly tweak the memory settings. But I am not sure about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without tweaking any memory settings I could run a pi example with 1 mapper and 1 reducer sometimes only on the free tier t2.micro instance, it fails most of the time.
By using the memory optimized r3.large instance with 15GB RAM everything works perfect. All jobs get completed without failure.